# How to set max string length for UIAlertView text field

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uialertview, textfield

How can I set the max string length for a textfield created within a `UIAlertView`?  I am using Xcode 4.5 and building the app on 10.8 (OS X)  Currently I have `UIAlertView` that launches when the user clicks a button.  The user will scan their RFID badge, and I want the input textfield of the `UIAlertView` to be limited to 10 (ten) characters so the user can't fudge association process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the above answer is *almost* right.

When typing single characters, range.length (for this method) appears to always be zero, while the location increments.

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

      NSLog(@"Range: %@", NSStringFromRange(range));
      return ( range.location < 10 );

 }
```

*edit:* length would probably be longer if you doing something other than single-character typing, i.e. pasting a line, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the length of the text in the delegate method of the textField:

```
textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
```

And return NO if you don't want to change.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
   if (textField.text.length - range.length + string.length > 10) {
      return NO;
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: This logic is incorrect. It should be `if (textField.text.length - range.length + string.length > 10)`. The location of the range is irrelevant. And you don't take into account the current text or the new text. Example - caret is at start of text with no selection and then I paste in 20 characters. Your code still returns YES.

Comment: I implemented the above method, but I am still able to input more than 10 characters.

Comment: I actually prefer your logic to my answer below. More scalable. Gonna remove mine. ;-) ... _edit_ guess it won't let me.